# in ST3 how do you invoke selection matching in a snippet?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, multipleselection

Say you have 3 selections and you want to call a snippet to wrap those three selections like you would if you pasted them to the same number of new selections in a file. you can do this with one selection by adding `${1:$SELECTION}` to the snippet, but how do you do this with more than one?